# What is the References Window in the Heap Walker of Netbeans Profiler for?

Tags: java, netbeans, profiler, heap-dump

Below is a picture of the References Window from the Heap Dump of a JavaFX application profiled using the Netbeans Profiler.
Can anyone tell me what this means?
What are in the "field", "type", and "value" columns?
Also, what does the blue and red arrow on JNI global mean?
Why is "classLoader" enclosed in less than (<) and greater than (>) signs? 
Which references which anyway? 
Any more points to remember?

[image]

I tried searching for these already, but I can't seem to find the answers.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'References Window' shows you the places from where your particular instanced is referenced.

'Field' is the field which keeps the reference. The 'Type' and 'Value' identify the referer instance.

The annotation icons (eg. the blue arrow) are described in the UI.

The ‘<classloader>‘ is formatted like this because it is not a real field. Rather it is an implicit relation between the class and its classloader.

Comment: Hello, thank you. What did you mean when you said "annotation icons (eg. the blue arrow) are described in the UI"?

Comment: At the bottom of the heapwalker window there is a row of icons with text labels. They correspond to the icons used in the UI.

Comment: That was hard to notice. Thanks again!